# How to delete pdf files with a window commande from many folders

Tags: command-line

I have a folder "Folder1" that contains several subfolders. Each subfolder contains pdf files. Is there a windows command that allows me to remove all these pdf from all subfolders without specifying the names of pdf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to access the file "Folder1" with the commande line 
cd [path Folder1]
Then we excute the command :
Del /S /Q *.pdf

All the files pdf under Folder1 and its subfolders will be deleted.